# How to display the_tags() as plain text

Tags: tags

`the_tags` by default is displaying as URL. I need to display it as plain text to insert inside HTML attribute.

```
<?php 
    $tag = the_tags('');
?>

<div class="image-portfolio" data-section="<?php echo $tag ?>">
```

Comment: Can't you simply use [`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/)?

Comment: i tried by had this error:  Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string..  This how i used it:  $tag = get_the_tags();
       foreach($tag as $tags) {
        echo $tags;
       }

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad you figured it out, but below is a quick semantic alteration (swapping your use of `$tag` singular and `$tags` plural will help it read closer to what it is doing; functionally it is no different).

I also added cases for inside and outside the Loop, and a conditional so you don't end up trying to foreach loop when there are no tags.

### Commented:

```
//We are inside the Loop here. Other wise we must pass an ID to get_the_tags()

    //returns array of objects
    $tags = get_the_tags();

    //make sure we have some
    if ($tags) {

        //foreach entry in array of tags, access the tag object
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {

           //echo the name field from the tag object 
           echo $tag->name;
        }
    }
```

### Inside Loop

```
    $tags = get_the_tags();

    if ($tags) {

        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {

            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }
```

### Outside Loop:

```
    $id = '10';

    $tags = get_the_tags( $id );

    if ($tags) {

        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {

            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }
```

---

### Further

Inside [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), [`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) uses the current post id. Outside of the loop, you need to pass it an id.
Either way, it returns an *array* of [`WP_TERM`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) *objects* for each term associated with the relevant post.

```
[0] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 
        [name] => 
        [slug] => 
        [term_group] => 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 
        [taxonomy] => post_tag
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 
        [count] => 
    )
```

You could access each value the same way as above, i.e.:

```
    $tags = get_the_tags(); 
    if ($tags) {
        foreach( $tags as $tag ) {

            echo $tag->term_id;
            echo $tag->name;
            echo $tag->slug;
            echo $tag->term_group;
            echo $tag->term_taxonomy_id;
            echo $tag->taxonomy;
            echo $tag->description;
            echo $tag->parent;
            echo $tag->count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this - why do we need to do `$tag->name` and can't do `$tag["name"]`? (I'm learning PHP right now and that seems to be a legit way to return an object key's value, unless I'm missing something?)

Answer (score 3):

Ok i figure it out

```
$tag = get_the_tags();
foreach($tag as $tags) {
    echo $tags->name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I love single lined codes, don't you?

```
<?php echo implode(' ,', wp_get_post_tags( get_the_ID(), array('fields' => 'names') ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will display the tags as a comma-space separated string:

```
echo join(', ', array_map(function($t) { return $t->name; }, get_the_tags()));
```